# Foreach syntax issue have used code in different project now broken

Tags: php, mysql, html, foreach, syntax

[image]

So my problem is I do not understand why I am getting this error as I have used this code previously for a different task and it worked. Here is the sample code:

```
  <?php

  include('assets/php/sql/con.php');

  if (isset($_GET['age'])) {
    $AGE = $_GET['age'];
    $GENDER = $_GET['gender'];

      $results = DB::query('SELECT * FROM gift_db WHERE age =:age',array(':age' => $_GET['age']))[0]['age'];

      // DB::query('SELECT * FROM gift_db WHERE age=:age', array(':age'=>$_GET['age']));
      $allResults = "";
      foreach ($results as $r) {

        $allResults = $r;

    }
  }
   ?>
```

If anyone would be able to help out that would be amazing. Thanks :)

Comment: you should fetch results before pass to `foreach`

Comment: You're assigning the value of age from the first result to `$results` with `[0]['age']`, so `$results` is not an array.

Comment: which framework or CMS you are using?

Comment: There is no need for `foreach` as `$results` already contains the value of `age` from the 1st row.

Comment: Simply put `$results = 20` i.e. its not an array its the age of the first person selected by your query

Comment: i'm confused as to how this worked initially

Comment: Also, even if the while loop were necessary, that while loop would set `$allResults` to be the LAST row selected by your query as it overwrites `$allResults` each time round the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When use query function this function returned an array but you selected the first element of this array.

> $results = DB::query('SELECT * FROM gift_db WHERE age =:age',array(':age' => $_GET['age']))[0]['age'];

Can you try with:

> $results = DB::query('SELECT * FROM gift_db WHERE age =:age',array(':age' => (int) $AGE));

It's possible in your code insert any value on age.

PD:Sorry for my English

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `$AGE` is coming as a string, not an integer, so can you please try like below:-

```
$results = DB::query('SELECT * FROM gift_db WHERE age =:age',array(':age' => (int) $AGE));
```